# How to put error logs in code when using pattern matching?

Tags: scala

I have a function convert date time to epoch, and I want to put some logs where it failed. Such as `case _ =>` and `.getOrElse(JNothing)` , how can I do that?

```
def time_to_epoch(params: List[JValue]): JValue = params match {
  case JString(timestamp) :: JString(pattern) :: JString(timezone) :: Nil =>
    Try {
      ***
    }.getOrElse(JNothing) // for saying something similar to can't convert time to epoch 
   case _ =>
     JNothing // Add a (ErrorMessage(xxxxxxx)) for saying number of parameters are invalid and what are expected inline function forma
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def time_to_epoch(params: List[JValue]): JValue = params match {
  case JString(timestamp) :: JString(pattern) :: JString(timezone) :: Nil =>
    Try {
      //***
    }.getOrElse {
      log.error("Cant ...")
      JNothing
    } 
   case _ =>
      log.error("Number ...")
     JNothing
}
```

For functional programming solution, there's treelog you can use, but it's really not necessary in your case, unless you need the function to be strictly pure.

Answer (score 1):

If `time_to_epoch` can fail then it is better to return a `Try` rather than a special failure value like `JNothing`.

```
case class MyException(msg: String) extends Exception

def time_to_epoch(params: List[JValue]): Try[JValue] = params match {
  case JString(timestamp) :: JString(pattern) :: JString(timezone) :: Nil =>
    Try {
      ???
    }
  case _ =>
    Failure(MyException("Invalid parameters"))
}
```

You can print the error information using `match`:

```
time_to_epoch(???) match {
  case Failure(e) =>
    println(s"Operation failed: $e")
  case _ =>
}
```

The advantage of this is that it is easy to chain multiple `Try` operations without having to test for failure at each step. It allows the code to focus on the main code path while still handling errors correctly.